# Python Tkinter call two functions with one button click (one is destroy())

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

New to tkinter. I should've implemented my GUI using classes but at this point it is too late to start fresh.

Goal:

I have a button `Button A` in the `main_window`. Upon clicking `Button A` I want to call another function `func1` (which will do some work and call another function `func2` to draw another window) and also close the `main_window` (or close main window first, then call func1, order doesn't matter).

My code:

I tried to use lambda to pass two functions but it gives me error

in `main_window.py`:

```
from another_file import func2

def func1(some args):
    # some work, args become arg2
    func2(arg2)

def main_window(some args):
    root = Tk()
    # some work
    btt = ttk.Button(frame, text="Button A", command=lambda: [root.destroy(), func(some args)])
    # some other work
    root.mainloop()
```

in `another_file` I just let it draw another window such as

```
def func2(arg2):
    root = Tk()
    # some work
    root.mainloop()
```

the error I got is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/path/to/main_window.py", line 121, in <lambda>
    btt = ttk.Button(frame, text="Button", command=lambda: [root.destroy(), func1(some args)])
  File /path/to/main_window.py", line 24, in func1
    some_variable_str = some_variable.get()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3082, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!entry"
```

If I switch from `command=lambda: [root.destroy(), func(some args)]` to `command=lambda: [func(some args), root.destroy()]` then the window from `main_window.py` won't be destroyed. After I close this window manually, it complains `_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed`

if I replace `root.destroy()` with a simpler function, e.g. `print("hello, world")`, it works fine

if I only have `func1` passed to the button command, it works fine (the `get()` function is good)

if I only have `root.destroy()` passed to the button command, it can close the windows without an issue.

Comment: does calling `root.destroy` before the actual code in your function definition not work?

Comment: Don't use lambda. Create a proper function, they are much easier to debug.

Comment: Why do you need to move from one window to another?

Comment: by design we have multiple windows to carry different functionalities. we didn't find a good way to catch tkinter widget handler function's return, therefore we are jumping from main_window to func1 then to func2.. We wanted to keep all backend logic in a same file but unfortunately we don't have a way to make it happen

Comment: Typo, it should be func1(some args). U needed to do TopLevel()

Answer (score 0):

Based on your traceback, you want to retrieve the string from the entry after destroying the root instance that the entry is associated with.

```
in func1
some_variable_str = some_variable.get()
```

You can get the string before destroying the root, or store the string in a variable.

---

**Using [StringVar](https://tkdocs.com/pyref/stringvar.html) along with [Entry](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#entry)**

main_window.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from another_file import func2

    
def func1(arg):
    arg2 = arg.get() # string_var.get()
    func2(arg2)
    
    
def main_window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    string_var = tk.StringVar(root)
    
    frame = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    entry = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=string_var)
    entry.pack()
    btt = ttk.Button(frame, text="Button A", command=lambda: [root.destroy(), func1(string_var)])
    btt.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    # you can get value after destroying root
    print("StringVar value:", string_var.get())
    # next line raises error _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!entry"
    # print(entry.get())


main_window()
```

another_file.py

```
import tkinter as tk


def func2(arg2):
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(text=f"{arg2}")
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```